# AOE2 DE: How to disable debug information?

Tags: steam, linux, age-of-empires-ii-de, dxvk

Some time ago I somehow enabled debug information in AOE2 DE, which is displayed in top left corner all the time (including main menu, etc.). This information sadly cannot be disabled by pressing F5 / F11 during the game. I have tried googling, but found nothing and I can't remember how I enabled this information.

My OS is Debian 10, and I am playing the game using Proton 5.0-10.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found it! It is easily found in general settings of the game.
Can't believe I am this stupid.. :D

[image]